# error en python: mala indentacion

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python y no encuentro el error ya puse mas espacios pero no logro compilar muchas gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que version de sublimetext usas ?

Comment: tambien fijate que names =.... tiene un espacio demas con relacion a las lineas de abajo...linea 7

Comment: @DiegoAvila version 3.1.1

Comment: Lo dice el error: Linea 8. Si te fijas, la instrucción anterior tiene un espacio de más al comienzo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En python la indentación sirve para marcar dónde comienza un nuevo bloque *y dónde termina*.

Aunque la forma en que indentas es libre (puedes usar espacios o tabuladores y el número de ellos que quieras), debe ser **consistente**.

Con esto quiere decirse que, o bien usas tabuladores siempre, o bien espacios siempre. Se recomienda lo segundo.

Cuando debe comenzar un nuevo bloque (por ejemplo, tras la línea `def funcion():`, o tras una condición `if condicion:`, o tras un inicio de bucle `for`, etc.. en general *siempre que una línea termina con dos puntos*, la línea siguiente debe ir indentada, esto es, debe tener más espacios por la izquierda que la anterior.

Esto indica para python que comienza un nuevo bloque (sería el equivalente a abrir una llave en otros lenguajes de programación).

Todas las líneas que componen ese bloque deben tener la misma indentación (el mismo número de espacios por la izquierda). Si dentro del bloque se abre otro sub-bloque, se indentará éste con más espacios.

Python da el bloque por terminado cuando una línea de pronto tiene menos espacios por la izquierda que la línea anterior. Esto equivaldría a "cerrar llave" en otros lenguajes. Pero de hecho podemos estar terminando un bloque anidado, lo que requeriría cerrar más de una llave en otros lenguajes. ¿Cómo sabe python cuántas llaves (imaginarias) debe cerrar?

Lo sabe porque **la indentación de la línea en cuestión debe coincidir con la de alguna línea previa**. Eso permite saber a python a qué "bloque" regresas una vez terminado el bloque anidado.

Eso precisamente es lo que te falla en tu código. Tienes esto:

```
def main():
      linea1
     linea2
     linea3
```

Tras la cabecera de la función python espera una línea indentada. La encuentra (`linea1`). Todo va bien.

La línea siguiente debería tener la misma indentación que `linea1` (en cuyo caso aún formaría parte del bloque, es decir, del código de `main()`), o bien, si tiene menos indentación, su indentación debería coincidir con la del `def main` (en cuyo caso se entiende que esa línea ya está fuera del bloque y por tanto no forma parte de `main()`.

En tu caso se encuentra con que la línea `linea2` tiene una indentación menor que `linea1`, pero que no coincide con la indentación de `def`, por tanto de da el error *Unindent does not match any outer indentation*, que de hecho literalmente significa "La desindentación no encaja con ninguna otra indentación exterior"

Comment: muchas gracias si ya me funciono,no sabia que fuera tan importante

Comment: Lo es, porque python no tiene otra forma de saber dónde empieza o acaba un bloque. Su creador ha decidido (contra viento y marea y a pesar de las críticas en contra) que el lenguaje no tendría delimitadores de bloque (habituales en otros lenguajes, en los que suele ser la llave o la palabra `end` o similares). Esta decisión de diseño está encaminada a _obligar_ a todos los programadores principiantes a indentar correctamente. Debo decir que me parece acertadísimo :-) El código mal indentado es muy difícil de leer.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos primero que nada verifica tu codigo, tienes un espacio demas en la linea 7, con respecto a las lineas siguientes, 8...9..etc.

Te sugiero establecer  o definir el tab a 4 espacios generalmente:

```
En el menú vas a View > Indentation > Tab width: 4.
```

segun lo que desees para mi me funciono con 4 .

Para mayor informacion ve a la documentacion:

[Documentacion Sublimetext](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/indentation.html)

Espero te ayude.!!

Comment: ya lo tengo asi  y me sigue marcando el mismo error